# DataFrame Groupby apply on second dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have 2 dataframes `df1, df2`. Both have `id` as a column. I want to compute a new column, `weighted_average`, in `df1` that is a function of the values in `df2` with the same `id`.

First, I think I should do `df1.groupby("id")`. Is it possible to use `GroupBy.apply(...)` and have it use values from `df2`? In the examples I've seen, it usually just operates on `df1` values.

Comment: Could you add some input examples of the two dataframes and the expected output of those?

Answer (score 0):

If they have same id positions and length, you can do some like:

```
df2["new column name"] = df1["column name"].apply(...)
```

Comment: They have the same `id`, but not the same length